# Using key for AsyncSelect doesn't show the value for the dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have used an AsyncSelect for my application and now I have a problem that I have been trying to solve for hours: I want that as soon as I click on the dropdown menu, the data is fetched again and displayed in the dropdown menu. On a forum I read that I can only achieve this if I set a `key` and change the value again and again.
The problem now is that as soon as I change the key, the selected value is no longer displayed in the dropdown menu (so as soon as I select a value, it is no longer displayed in the field. It is virtually overwritten). What am I doing wrong? How can I prevent this or is there another cleaner way to solve this?

```
class AsyncSearchFieldRules extends Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        key:"",
        query: ""
      }
    this.setQuery = this.setQuery.bind(this)       
    this.setKey = this.setKey.bind(this)
}

setQuery(query){
    console.log('Query:', query);
    this.setState({query:query})
    setKey()
}

setKey(){
    this.setState({key: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)})
}

render () {
    return (
        <div class="SearchfieldContainer">
        <AsyncSelect
        key={this.state.key}
        styles={customStyles}
        cacheOptions
        defaultOptions
        getOptionLabel={this.props.getOptionLabel}
        getOptionValue={this.props.getOptionValue}
        loadOptions={this.props.loadOptions}
        onInputChange={(value) => {this.setQuery(value)}}
        onMenuOpen={this.props.loadOptions()}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        onChange={(value) => {
            this.props.setSelected(value)
          }}              
        filterOption={null}
    />
        </div>

    )
}
}
export default AsyncSearchFieldRules
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. The problem that I was experiencing is due to the fact that every time when I changed the key, the `AsyncSelect` component is re-rendered and therefore the selected value is no longer displayed in the dropdown menu. One solution to this problem is to store the selected value in the state of the component and re-assign it after the key is changed:

```
class AsyncSearchFieldRules extends Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    key: '',
    query: '',
    selectedValue: null,
  };
  this.setQuery = this.setQuery.bind(this);
  this.setSelectedValue = this.setSelectedValue.bind(this);
}

setQuery(query) {
  console.log('Query:', query);
  this.setState({ query: query }, () => {
    this.setKey();
  });
}

setSelectedValue(value) {
  console.log('Selected value:', value);
  this.setState({ selectedValue: value });
}

setKey() {
  const { query, selectedValue } = this.state;
  const key = `${query}-${selectedValue}`;
  console.log('Key:', key);
  this.setState({ key });
}

render () {
    return (
        <div class="SearchfieldContainer">
        <AsyncSelect
        key={this.state.key}
        styles={customStyles}
        cacheOptions
        defaultOptions
        getOptionLabel={this.props.getOptionLabel}
        getOptionValue={this.props.getOptionValue}
        loadOptions={this.props.loadOptions}
        onInputChange={(value) => {this.setQuery(value)}}
        onMenuOpen={this.props.loadOptions()}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        onChange={(value) => {
            this.props.setSelected(value)
          }}              
        filterOption={null}
    />
        </div>

    )
}
}
export default AsyncSearchFieldRules
```